# Front-end and back-end separation -> Case with HEROKU

Tags: git, heroku, github, gitlab, git-flow

Me and my friend are currently working on the same project. We have two different git (GitLab) repos for each of us, which are **SPAGHETTI-WEB** and **SPAGHETTI-LIVE**. My friend is working on front-end (Angular) and developing the web for the backend. And I am doing the backend on Node JS. We currently host my back-end with his (web's) static files (in */root/public*) in the Heroku.

But the thing is that it is really pain in the ass for us all the time pull/push the stuff as we frequently encounter the **merge conflicts**. It still seems like we are working on different repos, but we end up pushing in one (into back-end, as it serves the pages). Project is not small and I cannot just copy/paste his built static files into repo. So, as he finishes developing his web, he pushes into `master` branch. And imagine that he has not the same server files as I do, and he `git pull` leaving me the **merge conflicts** (when I want to add/commit/push into the repository).

### **So, the question is:**

Can you think of any strategy to keep working on a separate repos and at the same be *code friendly* and prevent those *merge conflicts* (basically, to be more independent from each other)? And do you think that **Docker** can help us in this case? (asking because never worked with it before).

**Current status:**

As of solutions, we thought something about using Heroku FTP, but I do not thing this gonna work as it is not proper way to work like that. Or, probably, create the **HEROKU-WEB** and **HEROKU-APP** where my friend will send requests from **HEROKU-WEB** to **HEROKU-APP**

This is how it works now:

```
 BACKEND-------\
                \
                 ---> GITLAB REPO (i.e. Back-end) --> HEROKU
                /
 FRONTEND------/
```

How we want it:

```
 BACKEND Work--\
                --> SERVER-REPO
                               \
                                 ---> HEROKU
                               /                   
                --> WEB-REPO
 FRONTEND Work-/
```

Comment: why can't you seperate the 2 and have 2 seperate Heroku apps, one for front end the other for backend?

Comment: As of back-end now, I have DEV and LIVE (production) instances. I am not sure that creating 4 in total instances of Heroku (2 Front-end ones, web-dev and web-live, and 2 back-end ones, backend-dev and backend-live) is the best way to handle this issue.